# Editing the date formatting of x-axis tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I am looking to edit the formatting of the dates on the x-axis. The picture below shows how they appear on my bar graph by default. I would like to remove the repetition of 'Dec' and '2012' and just have the actual date numbers along the x-axis.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: The answer here worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In short:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

Many examples on the matplotlib website. The one I most commonly use is [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)

Comment: Is there an alternative method without using the `ax.xaxis` but using `plt.<command>`?

Comment: @3kstc Maybe, but I can't imagine a situation where ambiguously relying on the state machine is preferable to the more explicit command.

Comment: For a quick view of all possible datetime formats, use [strftime.org](http://strftime.org).

Comment: My dates are timezone aware and the DateFormatter converts times to UTC.  I needed to add the timezone like so:  mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M', pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).

Comment: Note `ax` is defined in the answer by @Robino

Comment: @3kstc If you want to use `plt` instead of `ax` you can do: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)`

Comment: Thanks @charelf, lastly is there a way of changing the step/frequency of x ticks with using 'plt.<command>'?

Comment: @3kstc `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(....)`

Comment: @PaulH I assume `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(...) `

Comment: `plt.gca()` returns the Axes object, which you should define ahead of time

Answer (score 61):

While the answer given by Paul H shows the essential part, it is not a complete example. On the other hand the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) seems rather complicated and does not show how to use days.

So for everyone in need here is a full working example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

myDates = [datetime(2012,1,i+3) for i in range(10)]
myValues = [5,6,4,3,7,8,1,2,5,4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(myDates,myValues)

myFmt = DateFormatter("%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

## Rotate date labels automatically
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

From the package [matplotlib.dates](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) as shown in this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) the date format can be applied to the axis label and ticks for plot.

Below I have given an example for labeling axis ticks for multiplots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('US_temp.csv')
plt.plot(df['Date'],df_f['MINT'],label='Min Temp.')
plt.plot(df['Date'],df_f['MAXT'],label='Max Temp.')
plt.legend()
####### Use the below functions #######
dtFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b') # define the formatting
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dtFmt) # apply the format to the desired axis
plt.show()
```

As simple as that

Answer (score 3):

This wokrs prfectly for me

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dtFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b') # define the formatting
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dtFmt) 
# show every 12th tick on x axes
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontweight='light',  fontsize='x-small',)
```

[image: formating example]