# time format of xaxis does not change correctly on pandas' plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot pandas DataFrame as a line chart with x-axis having '%H:%M' style.

However, when I try this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(9)])
d.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(15,24)]
ax = d.plot(xticks=d.index)
plt.xticks([x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in d.index][0::4])
```

Chart with %H:%M:%s style x-axis is ploted:

[image]

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib), I've added `DateFormatter`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
d = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(9)])
d.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(15,24)]
ax = d.plot(xticks=d.index)
#plt.xticks([x.strftime("%H:%M") for x in d.index][0::4])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

Unfortunately, I got a plot with only 00:00 x-axis.

[image]

I'd like to get %H:%M style x-axis with proper interval ticks label like "15:00, 17:00, 19:00, 21:00" (every 2 intervals here). How do I realize that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is happening because DateFormatting is not recognizing the instructions for "`%H:%M`". Just replace those by the integer instruction, `%d`, and it should give you the result you want (or at least something you can adapt). In the following fix of your code I also added rotation to labels to avoid excessive cluttering in the x-axis:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
d = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(9)])
d.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(15,24)]
ax = d.plot(xticks=d.index)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Changed here
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%d:%d')) # and here...
plt.show()
```

EDIT: The example above only changes the interpreter string for the formatter. I didn't mess with the data or anything else. In any case ideally you should be using this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,24,2)))
```

, to achieve what you want. But I just tested it and it appears to have a bug. That being said my advice is that you parse directly your desired labels into the xticks.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(9)])
d.index = [datetime.time(i, 0).hour for i in range(15,24)]
ax = d.plot(xticks=d.index)
plt.xticks([datetime.time(i, 0).hour for i in range(15,24)][0::2],["%d:00"%datetime.time(i, 0).hour for i in range(15,24)][0::2],rotation=45)  # Changed here
plt.show()
```

, which results in this:

[image: x label with hours with a step of 2]

Comment: I just changed what I felt was your most urgent problem: the fact that your labels were zeroed no matter the location (the rest I assumed you would adapt). Down voting an answer just because it does not give a copy paste solution seems like a new trend in SO. Personally I find it regrettable but I guess that's how it is. I've edited the post with a possible solution to your problem.