# Get number of fails and successes from a dataframe in time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With a dataFrame like this:

```
Time                    Status      ResponseTime     PID
2016-07-13 17:33:49     OK          1623             42
2016-07-13 17:33:50     KO          1593             35
2016-07-13 17:33:50     OK          1604             19
2016-07-13 17:33:51     KO          1605             28
2016-07-13 17:33:51     OK          1617             42
2016-07-13 17:33:52     OK          1654             35
2016-07-13 17:33:52     OK          2044             19
2016-07-13 17:33:53     KO          1630             42
```

How can I draw a kind of a histogram which would present number of KOs and OKs for each minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = """Time                    Status      ResponseTime     PID
2016-07-13 17:33:49     OK          1623             42
2016-07-13 17:33:50     KO          1593             35
2016-07-13 17:33:50     OK          1604             19
2016-07-13 17:33:51     KO          1605             28
2016-07-13 17:33:51     OK          1617             42
2016-07-13 17:33:52     OK          1654             35
2016-07-13 17:33:52     OK          2044             19
2016-07-13 17:33:53     KO          1630             42
2016-07-13 17:34:49     OK          1623             42
2016-07-13 17:34:50     KO          1593             35
2016-07-13 17:34:50     OK          1604             19
2016-07-13 17:34:51     KO          1605             28
2016-07-13 17:34:51     OK          1617             42
2016-07-13 17:34:52     OK          1654             35
2016-07-13 17:34:52     OK          2044             19
2016-07-13 17:34:53     KO          1630             42
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

df1 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('Min')).Status.value_counts().unstack()
df1
```

[image]

```
df1.plot.bar()
```

[image]

If you want to limit to `'KO'`:

```
df1.KO.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: And if I would like to filter results only to OK or KO ?

Comment: And one more question, how to format Time axis to show only hour and minute?

Comment: @kulawyjoe simple way is to `df1.index = df1.index.strftime('%H:%M')`.  Then run plots.

Comment: @kulawyjoe a better answer is found here --- > http://stackoverflow.com/a/14946444/2336654