# Mixed format dates in python matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

How can I get a matplotlib x-axis date with the format Mon-%d-%Y?  In other words, with the month spelled out either in full or with a three char abbreviation?

Comment: What format is your data in? Can we see an example?

Comment: Are you looking for the `%b` directive? See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime), "locale's abbreviated month name".

Comment: In addition to the correct formatting code per whrrgarbl, to apply it to the entire axis use `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` per the question answered here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Add the code showing the basic data set and the non-working plot.