# How to set the graph with dates on the x axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, quandl

I'm creating code that takes financial data from QUANDL
The problem is that I can't format the chart by date.
I searched the internet and saw that I have to use the matplotlib.dates library
Here I paste the code.
Would anyone be able to help me?

I want to see the date in this format:
10-10-2018

```html
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
#matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

from matplotlib import style


start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.date.today()


s = "AAPL"

#token = ""
#add authtoken = token
df = quandl.get("WIKI/" + s, start_date = start, end_date = end)



# df['10ma'] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean().shift()
df['10ma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window = 10, min_periods= 0).mean()
df['20ma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window = 20, min_periods= 0).mean()



plt.show()
```

[OUTPUT WITH print(df.head)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYle7.png)

```html
              Open    High     Low  ...  Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume
Date                                ...                                   
2018-01-02  170.16  172.30  169.26  ...    169.26      172.26   25048048.0
2018-01-03  172.53  174.55  171.96  ...    171.96      172.23   28819653.0
2018-01-04  172.54  173.47  172.08  ...    172.08      173.03   22211345.0
2018-01-05  173.44  175.37  173.05  ...    173.05      175.00   23016177.0
2018-01-08  174.35  175.61  173.93  ...    173.93      174.35   20134092.0

[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your data *in text form*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing the date formatting of x-axis tick labels in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I tried to do this but I don't understand how to do it correctly, can someone write it programmatically?