# Avoid interpreting strings as dates when plotting categorical data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, categorical-data, python-datetime

I am trying to plot categorical data in matplotlib with string entries that look like dates but are not dates.  Matplotlib tries to automatically convert the string to a datetime object, but fails.  How can I force matplotlib to treat the categories as strings and prevent it from trying to convert the string to a datetime object?

Here's my example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
categories = ['2019-20', '2020-21']
vals = [5, 10]
plt.plot(categories, vals)
```

Which gives

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-20'
<...snip...>
calendar.IllegalMonthError: bad month number 20; must be 1-12
```

For what it's worth, in my example, the strings represent academic years (2019-2020 and 2020-2021), but matplotlib assumes that they are dates in the form YYYY-MM and throws and error when trying to convert "20" and "21" to a valid month.

If I change the categories to ['2019-2020', '2020-2021'], the code works fine (matplotlib no longer assumes the strings represent a datetime object).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
categories = ['2019-2020', '2020-2021']
vals = [5, 10]
plt.plot(categories, vals)
```

[image]

But I prefer to use the shorter version YYYY-YY rather than the longer YYYY-YYYY.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib Maybe this would help. Im pretty sure theres a way for plt to format to what you want.

Comment: Not relevant, I think... that link shows how to format date strings on the x-axis, but my x-axis categories are not dates. Imagine instead of "academic year", the string "2019-20" represented the 20th shelf in aisle 2019 of a giant warehouse.

Comment: I just tried your example that returned the error and did not get the error. Perhaps try upgrading matplotlib? Quite unlike matplotlib to convert strings to datetime

Comment: I'm using the latest version (`matplotlib 3.1.2`).  You get a valid plot with `categories=['2019-20', '2020-21']` ?

Comment: This is fixed in `matplotlib 3.2` which is on RC3.  I'm actually not clear *why* it is fixed based on a bisect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plt.plot will try to do a X-Y Cartesian coordinate type plot if you pass in two positional args. I think you need something like `plot(vals)` only and then call plt.xticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
categories = ['2019-20', '2020-21']
vals = [5, 10]
plt.plot(vals)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(vals)), tuple(categories))
```

refer to https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: thank you -- this does work (added full MWE), but I'd also like to know if it's possible to prevent matplotlib from automatically trying to convert a string to a datetime object.

Comment: that is a side effect of what you are trying to do. plt.plot() takes 1 or 2 iterables of numerical values as positional arguments and tries to project them onto a 2D space. It just so happens that it recognized your `categories` as numerical and tried to project them as `x` coordinates. It would throw a different error if your categories were something akin to `['cat', 'dog']`.

Comment: I don't follow -- my original code works fine with both `['cat','dog']` and with `['2019-2020', '2020-2021']` as `categories`, which is the expected behavior as given in https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html (at least for `matplotlib 3.1.2`).  Anyway, I've accepted your answer since it does what I need and it came in first.

Comment: ah okay. Thanks I didn't know about this behaviour. I assume it tries to short-circuit the xticks step.

Answer (score 0):

While you code works fine in my old version (`matplotlib 2.2.2`), you can try the following workaround. The trick is to use the `categories` as custom x-ticklabels

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categories = ['2019-20', '2020-21']
vals = [5, 10]
plt.plot(range(len(categories)), vals)

plt.xticks(range(len(categories)), categories);
```

Comment: thanks Sheldore, this code works, and is more minimal (no numpy needed).