# How to get x axis labels on chart when plotting df using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have minutely data in a dataframe. I'm trying to plot on y axis column `C`, against the index column date. How can I show 5 `dates` as x-axis labels?

Currently, I try to plot like this:

```
df['C'].plot(figsize=(16,6))
```

However, I can't see any x-axis labels.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["2020-07-01 00:00:00",2],["2020-07-01 00:01:00",3]],columns=['date','C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

- Read the `dataframe` :

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["2020-07-01 00:00:00",2],["2020-07-01 00:01:00",3]],columns=['date','C'])
```

- Change the `dtype` of `date` to pandas `datetime64[ns]`.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

- Plot with supplying `date` as `x` :

```
df.plot(x='date')
```

Output :

[image]

You can change the frequency of the ticks using `mdates.DateFormatter` as explained in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib):

```
## borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d') ## change '%d' depending on your requirement
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```