# Python Plot day time on x-axis for many years of data

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, time

I am plotting many years of data. On the x-axis, I am plotting time of the day and on y-axis the value. The problem is x-axis ticks builtup together, not visible. How do I solve it?

```
plt.plot(df.index.strftime('%H:%M'),df['ydata'],'.')#hour+ssdf.index.minute/60
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

In the above plot, I wanted to see the x-axis ticks show 00:00, 02:00, etc.

Comment: When you plot strings on the x-axis, you're telling matplotlib that your data is categorical, and therefore each distinct values needs to be shown. Plot the actual dates and use an axis label formatter instead

Comment: See, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

You can try the first answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib/12608937).

Reducing the number of xticks by using `plt.xticks` will change the frequency of items appearing.