# How to change frequency of x-axis tick label of datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, xticks

I try to plot some speed time graph in spyder, and I did some plots. My problem is the x label. I want to write the time in the x plane as `2012 2013 2014 2015 2016` but I can't. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_excel("ts80.xlsx")
Date=data["Date"]
Speed=data["Speed"]


timestamp = pd.to_datetime(Date[0:]).dt.strftime("%Y %m %d")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,6))
ax.plot(timestamp, Speed)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("80Avg[m/s]")
plt.title("Mean Wind Speed at 80m")
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator((1,15)))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y %m"))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

My output
[image: my code]

What I want

[image: what ı want]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You should always include a [minimal *working* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. do not read data from you HDD but write a little code that *generates* a toy example.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib).

You just need to play around a bit further with the other settings

- formatting the displayed date with `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%y')` as you already did
- setting the ticks of the x-axis to distinct values, either by using the function `matplotlib.pytplot.xticks()` or the method of an axis's object `ax.set_ticks()`. Note that they should be of the same type as your original ticks (i.e. `datetimes.date` in this case)
- limit the width of the x-axis with either `plt.xlim()` or `ax.set_xlim()`

I drew a little example here with different plots (see below)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


# create dummy data
y = np.random.randn(50)
x = [datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(len(y))]
# open figure
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
# flatten
axs = axs.flatten()

for i in range(4):
    axs[i].plot(x,y)

    # set x-axis date format
    if i > 0:
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%y')
        axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    # set x-axis ticks (to years)
    if i > 1:
        axs[i].set_xticks([datetime.date(i,1,1) for i in range(2020,2022)])
    # limit x-axis again
    if i > 2:
        axs[i].set_xlim((x[0],x[-1]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ticks: [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). For instance:

```py
plt.ticks([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016])
```

Comment: I tried but got an error for module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ticks'. Can you write all the code? I'm a beginner. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: It is not "ticks", it is "xticks".

Comment: its not working. I wrote plt.xticks([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]) here is what ı got. https://ibb.co/Qv92n6R