# matplotlib python data in ymd format but axis labels show y-month how to change

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data like below 83 rows and 2 columns

```
x1.head()

     x          y
79  2021-01-10  3755
80  2021-01-17  3680
81  2021-01-24  4192
82  2021-01-31  4587
83  2021-02-07  4398
```

But when i plot it using

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.grid()
plt.plot(x1['x'], x1['y']);
```

my x axis appears as below - in Year-month format. I would like to keep the format same as column x.

1. How to fix that?
2. why does it changes date format?
3. how to ensure that we get all x-axis labels

[image]

Comment: You need to set the date format for the x axis tick labels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946371/editing-the-date-formatting-of-x-axis-tick-labels-in-matplotlib

Comment: i tried it but struggled due to some other errors that started to come

Comment: could you show how to update the code, thanks!

Comment: What is the data type for the entries in `x`? If they are strings, then you will need to first convert them to datetime objects

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'DateFormatter ', in which you specify that you want to display year, month, day on the axis. For example, you can leave only the year and see how it works.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

The following is the code where the x1 column is converted to a date and the DateFormatter specifies the year, month, day.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

x1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['2021-01-10', '2021-01-17', '2021-01-24', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-07'],
                   'y': [3755, 3680, 4192, 4587, 4398]})

x1['x'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['x'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
plt.xlim(x1.loc[0,'x'], x1.loc[len(x1)-1,'x'])
ax.plot(x1['x'], x1['y'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(5))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: even if I drop lines `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()` from your code, it prints in ymd format so I am not sure whether `set_major_formatter` is working or not

Comment: also is there need of `x1['x'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['x'])`. Even without doing that line I get below output `x1.dtypes
x1.dtypes
x    datetime64[ns]
y             int64
dtype: object`

Comment: I used pd.to_datetime because I wasn't sure if the column type was in date format(have it in this case in string format). In what format do you need the date year, month, day, that is, divisions should look like this 2021-01-10?   You can use your data instead of my x1 frame and check.

Comment: also i noticed the dates that are printed are first of every other month. How to force to use values from our column `x`?

Comment: Updated the code. Specified size assignment. Also added LinearLocator, in which 5 means how many labels to draw along the axis. As for exactly displaying the labels from the column, I can’t say yet. Possibly tomorrow.

Comment: Updated code, set x-axis limits: plt.xlim(x1.loc[0,'x'], x1.loc[len(x1)-1,'x']). Now only the data that is in the column is displayed, at least it works for me.