# Seaborn convert BarPlot to histogram-like chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that looks like this, and I'm using it to graph the life of a character over period of days. The `days` column is really "days since birth." For this example, the character was born on May 26th, 2023.

```
   days  health  months
0     0    30    May 23
1     1    30    
2     2    20    
3     3    20    
4     4    10    
5     5    10    
6     6    10    Jun 23
7     7    10    
8     8    10    
9     9     0
```

This is the seaborn `BarPlot`.

[image]

**I have significantly simplified the number of days** the character is alive for the sake of reproducibility, but in my normal code, the number of days is in the hundreds, *possibly thousands*.

Here is a graph of my normal case.

[image]

As you can see, this graph is much more overloaded with bars, which seems to be impacting performance pretty negatively, with only a few hundred days.

So my question is this: can I convert the `BarPlot` to the seaborn equivalent of a histogram with the way my `DataFrame` is set up?

The ideal would look something like the image below (ignore my bad graphic design job), **The red lines are only to highlight each section of the histogram. I am not looking to add those red lines.**

Note, I also need to be able to keep the month labels in the same place as they are above, since there could be a section of time where the character's health stays the same for multiple months.

[image]

My code is minimal for the chart, but the size of the `DataFrame` seems to be causing the slow rendering time.

```
ax = sns.barplot(dataframe, x='days', y='health', color='blue')
ax.set_xticklabels(dataframe.months)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Here's a line for the example `DataFrame`, for easy reproducibility:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'health': [30, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0], 'months': ["May 23", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Jun 23", " ", " ", " "]})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like it supposed to be a continuous x-axis, in which case, this should be a line plot.

Comment: Ah! I was only looking for histogram options. The answer was right in front of me. Thanks, @TrentonMcKinney!

Comment: Also going to add this comment: Since I had `days` as my x-value, I had hundreds of `xticklabels`, which seems to have impacted my rendering speed even more than just using the boxplot method. Changed my `df` so empty labels would be `""` instead of `" "` and this helped immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It seems like it's supposed to be a continuous x-axis, in which case, this should be a line plot.
- You don't want to plot strings on the x-axis. This results in a tick for every string because the labels are categorical.

  - Combine `'months'` and `'days'`, add a year, and create a datetime Dtype column to use as the x-axis.
- `pandas` will format the ticklabels differently based on the range of the dates.
- Customize the exact look and location of the datetime axis, by looking at the many questions on SO dealing with formatting datetime xtick labels.

  - [Editing the date formatting of x-axis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14946371/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'health': [30, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0], 'months': ["May 23", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Jun 23", " ", " ", " "]})

# replace the strings with NA, so forward fill will work
df = df.replace(' ', pd.NA)

# fill the months column, not empties
df.months = df.months.ffill()

# convert to a datetime with a specific year
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2023 ' + df.months, format='%Y %b %d')

# update the date column by adding the days as an offset
df.date = df.apply(lambda v: v.date + pd.Timedelta(days=v.days), axis=1)

# plot
ax = df.plot(x='date', y='health', rot=0, figsize=(10, 5))

# if the xticks labels need to be repositioned horizontally get the ticks and labels
ticks, labels = list(zip(*[(v.get_position()[0], v.get_text()) for v in ax.get_xticklabels()]))

# reset the ticks and labels
ax.set_xticks(ticks, labels, ha='center')
```

[image]

#### `df`

```
   days  health  months       date
0     0      30  May 23 2023-05-23
1     1      30  May 23 2023-05-24
2     2      20  May 23 2023-05-25
3     3      20  May 23 2023-05-26
4     4      10  May 23 2023-05-27
5     5      10  May 23 2023-05-28
6     6      10  Jun 23 2023-06-29
7     7      10  Jun 23 2023-06-30
8     8      10  Jun 23 2023-07-01
9     9       0  Jun 23 2023-07-02
```

#### `df.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   days    10 non-null     int64         
 1   health  10 non-null     int64         
 2   months  10 non-null     object        
 3   date    10 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 452.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the `width`:

```
ax = sns.barplot(df, x='days', y='health', color='blue', width=1)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.months)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Another way with `lineplot` as suggested by @TrentonMcKinney

```
ax = sns.lineplot(df, x='days', y='health', color='blue', drawstyle='steps-pre')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.months)
ax.fill_betweenx(df['health'], df['days'], color='blue', step='post')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]