# Float formatting: Plotting an strftime

Tags: python, matplotlib, strftime

I am formatting the original timestamps in my MongoDB documents. The original ones look like this:

```
"timestamp" : ISODate("2013-03-06T17:10:29Z")
```

And the formatted ones (Used as _id of the documents after using aggregation):

```
"_id" : "06-03-13T17:10"
```

I then want to plot the "amount" (y axis) values against the "_id" values (x axis)

I am having trouble formatting the _id so that I can plot it.

```
amount = [book["price"] for book in sorted["result"]]
time = [book["_id"] for book in sorted["result"]]
P.plot(amount, time)
P.show()
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 06-03-13T15:36
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `plot` function a string, which is not a valid x-axis format as far as I know. I'm pretty sure you want to have your original `datetime` objects, and then use `date2num` to format them to pass to matplotlib. So depending on if you're using the `strftime` formatted stuff for anything else, it might make more sense to store the output of `date2num` in your mapping, rather than the output of `strftime`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib) for a little more specificity and links to some examples.

Comment: thanks, but how would i manage to remove the seconds in my datetime objects?

Comment: @Julia do you need to remove the seconds from the datetimes, or just from the format string? You should be able to give matplotlib a `strftime` format string to use. If you need to strip seconds from your datetimes, that's just `dt = dt.replace(second=0)`.