# Alternating tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to alternate my x-axis tick labels across two levels. My labels now are:

A B C D

What I want would be

```
A   C
  B   D
```

But I can't seem to find how on google/docs/SO.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use minor ticks (defined via `set_minor_locator` and `set_minor_formatter`). Then you can shift e.g. all major ticks using `tick_params`:

```py
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter

pl.plot(range(100))

pl.axes().xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(range(0, 100, 10)))
pl.axes().xaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(range(5, 100, 10)))
pl.axes().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%d"))
pl.axes().tick_params(which='major', pad=20, axis='x')
```

[image]

But be careful with `FixedLocator`: To avoid generating major ticks twice (once as major and once as minor ticks) I chose fixed tick locations instead of using a `MultipleLocator`. You'll need to adjust these tick locations to your data and window size.

(Idea borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719672/3419103).)

Comment: This did the trick. Was hoping that I could just order major-ticks in the way requested, but this worked :).