# Limit Range on X Axis Scatter Plot Pandas MatplotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that is indexed based on time, with another column indicating the number of injured pedestrians during a crash occuring at that hour. I am trying to use Matplotlib in order to graph the data, and have successfully graphed it, however, the range is much too large. I have data for one day, and would like to set the x axis limit accordingly using the min and max values calculted. I have tried using plt.set_xlim but I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'

How can the limit be properly set?

Graph without limits
[image: Graph without limits]

```
df = test_request_pandas()
df1 = df[['time','number_of_pedestrians_injured']]
df1.set_index(['time'],inplace=True)
df1 = df1.astype(float)
min = df1.index.min()
max = df1.index.max()
fig = plt.scatter(df1.index.to_pydatetime(), df1['number_of_pedestrians_injured'])
#fig.set_xlim([min, max]) // causing me issues
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the range of the x-axis with datetimes in MatPlotLib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 4):

You can create axes and then use `ax.xlim()`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[3,4,5]})
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
df.plot(x='x',y='y',ax=ax, kind='scatter')
ax.set_xlim(2,3)
```

Comment: @IIya V. Schurov What does the 111 mean?

Comment: It creates a "subfigure matrix" with 1 row and 1 column. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111

Comment: @IIya V. Schurov I get "KeyError:time"

Comment: Using the command: df1.plot(x='time',y='number_of_pedestrians_injured', kind='scatter')

Comment: It seems to be sideeffect of `df1.set_index(['time'],inplace=True)`: after you do it, column `time` disappears from the dataframe as it becomes index.

Comment: You can still use `plt.scatter` instead of `df1.plot` as you do. For example, you can try `plt.xlim()` instead of `fig.set_xlim()` in your code.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib) question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `plt.xlim(min, max)` instead.