# Setting limits to a graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display data on a graph between 2002-2022 as shown in the attached image. I tried some methods to set it but it's not executing. How do I manually set the limits so the graphs do not show a compressed plot. 
[image: Graph the limits have to be set is in this link. ]]

Comment: try `plt.xlim('2002', '2022')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit Range on X Axis Scatter Plot Pandas MatplotLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404495/limit-range-on-x-axis-scatter-plot-pandas-matplotlib)