# moving the location of y labels with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I move the location of y labels?

[image]

And this is  the zoomed version:

[image]

The idea is to move the righthandside labels further to the right, because where they currently are is hard to see the last data point of each of the time series (in this case I circled in green where the last data point is). 
Tried `set_label_coords()`, but didn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Normally, the data does not flush out of the axis frame. You probably have done something that causes this. Can you tell us, what it is? Otherwise, just let your x axis go till the first of november.

Comment: Is not really going out of the axis frame, let me add a zoomed version and update.

Comment: Your data goes up to 3rd of october while in the non-zoomed version your last point on the x axis ist the first of october. So you should simply plot your data until the 3rd of october or beyond.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and instead of data use a couple of sine waves.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how would you do "Otherwise, just let your x axis go till the first of november."?, maybe that  will do the trick.

Comment: @Gabriel you can use `ax.set_xlim()` to set the axis limits. If you want an example code you first need to provide a minimal working example yourself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that worked! Do you  want to put  as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the data does not flush out of the axis frame. This might however differ for an axis with dates. Since your data goes up to 3rd of october while in the non-zoomed version your last point on the x axis ist the first of october, you should simply plot your data until the 3rd of october or beyond.

The axis limits can be set using the [`ax.set_xlim()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) command.

Also see [How do I change the range of the x-axis with datetimes in MatPlotLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

showing how I did it in the end after @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed the right direction:

1) created an extra date that is actually longer than the last day of my data

```
extradate   = pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime(df.index[-1].year,df.index[-1].month,df.index[-1].day + 5))
```

2) use that  extradate in:

```
ax.set_xlim(df.index[-100],extradate)
```

(the -100 is just to plot 100 points of data).