# Changing scale of seaborn plots for timestamp data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a timestamp column which I want to plot against, say, a name column which has several different names. But because my timestamps are within 1 day, my plot looks like this when I use `sns.swarmplot(x="name", y='datetime', data=dataset);`

[image]

I know how to change `ylim` or `set_yscale` to set the y-axis range from Jan 18 to Jan 19 (since all the values lie in Jan 19) but to scale it more, is there any way to set it over a few hours on the same day? Say, from 12am to 5pm of Jan 19?

Comment: I'm not sure if swarmplot is the correct plot to use here. In any case, how do you want your plot to look like? Also, provide  a [mcve] of the issue, such that people can provide a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to plot especially because your x-labels are overplotting. Can you please include some sample of the data. At first glance, I would say you use the false kind of plot or your data need further preparation.

Comment: Yes the data pre-processing might be an issue because I was experimenting swarmplots on various kind of data. This was generated on two columns - one had datetime values (y axis) and other had names(x axis). My general question, which I now see wasn't clear, is how to re-scale an axis which has datetime values.

Comment: In that case the question is already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Thanks. It is more or less similar. The original question has the same issue however, data is of the same date. Do you know what if I wanted to set range over a few hours in the same date?