# Using DateTimeIndex for set_xlim on matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

How can I set x/y limits on matplotlib to certain datetime values?

I got a DateTimeIndex object (called time) and i want the plots to fit inside the first and last value of this index.

If I try `ax.set_xlim(time[0],time[-1])`

it throws me this error:

```
Cannot compare type Timedelta with type float
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the range of the x-axis with datetimes in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time handling in matplotlib is gregorian, so it needs to be converted, I think it needs to be done with date2num().

[matplotlib API Overview: Dates](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num)

`ax.set_xlim(date2num([series_.index.min(), series_.index.max()]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))`

Comment: Cheers! Worked perfectly