# Is there a way in seaborn scatter plot to ajust xlim with datetime object

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, visualization

Codes used are as below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

sns.scatterplot(x='ReceivedDate',y='TotalDays',data=A ,hue='Track')
plt.xlim(2009-1-1,2019-1-1)
```

This is what iam getting. I want x lim to be between years 2012-2020.

[image]

Comment: codes used are as below:              plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.scatterplot(x='ReceivedDate',y='TotalDays',data=A ,hue='Track')
plt.xlim(2009-1-1,2019-1-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the range of the x-axis with datetimes in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib)