# start a line plot away from y axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, line-plot

code is as below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates = ['2010-11', '2011-12', '2012-13', '2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17']
steps = [9000, 9500.756, 9800.859, 10000.262, 9800.972, 10500.058, 11300.703]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set(xlabel="X-axis",ylabel="Y-axis",title="2d line plot",xlim=(0,8),ylim=(2000,15000))
ax.plot(dates,steps, color='red',linewidth=2,marker='o',label='LPG')
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

Running this code I am getting a plot as below

[image: line plot]

Here the plot is starting from y-axis how to push it little right

Comment: You can take a look at set_xticks and set_xticklabels

Comment: Has been answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib `ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2014, 1, 26), datetime.date(2014, 2, 1)])`

Answer (score 1):

In your command

```
ax.set(xlabel="X-axis",ylabel="Y-axis",title="2d line plot",xlim=(0,8),ylim=(2000,15000))
```

change the first number in parameter `xlim=(0,8)` to some negative value; use e.g. `xlim=(-.5,8)`:

```
ax.set(xlabel="X-axis",ylabel="Y-axis",title="2d line plot",xlim=(-.5,8),ylim=(2000,15000))
```

[image]