# Select specific part of x-axis in Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for a way where I can only plot a specific part of my time series.
I have an prediction model via the FB Prophet feature.
Please also see the plot below and code below. Any ideas how I could only plot dates between 2019 and 2021?

[image: Plot where I want to visluaize only dates between 2019 and 2021]

```
# plotting of predictions with actual values from 30-09-2020 until 30-10-2020; Combine Prediction and actual values
m_data_DJI_recent.plot(prediction_2)
plt.plot(df_DJI, color = "red")
plt.title("Prediction using the Prophet")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What part of [plt.xlim()](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) was the problem?

Comment: I tried also via plt.xlim() but struggled to find correct values. The plot then only showed a plank output. I don't really know what values to put for xlim. The date format used is year-month-day. @Mr.T

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21424306/8881141 This is difficult to say without you providing an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there with Mr. T's comment, their linked comment has the details. You can use

```
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 30)])
```

Replace the dates with the applicable dates for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the data directly like so (just simulated data used therefore a simple index, not a df, blue for reference):

```
# plotting of predictions with actual values from 30-09-2020 until 30-10-2020; Combine Prediction and actual values
#m_data_DJI_recent.plot(prediction_2)
df_DJI = np.random.randint(0,10,size=20)
plt.plot(df_DJI, color = "blue")
plt.plot(df_DJI[3:], color = "red") # limit range of plot
plt.title("Prediction using the Prophet")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.show()
```

For a dataframe this would look like this for dates:

```
df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-02-01']
```

(or see [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates) for df date restrictions)

Comment: This still plots both on the same chart, I believe OP means how to filter the plot to just that timeframe