# Setting custom years as dates on the plt x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Im trying to get the red curve to begin at the year 2020 and for the curves to end at the year 2030. However it keeps showing 1970s dates. How do I correct these?

[image]

```
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter
import pylab

years = YearLocator()   # every year
months = MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%Y')

J_diff = cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1]
J_diffint = cIncint[1:] - cIncint[:-1]
#J_diff = np.diff(cInc)
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
#ax.plot(t, U*100000, 'black', alpha=1, lw=2, label='uninfected')
#ax.plot(t, Lf/100000, 'r', alpha=1, lw=2, label='latent fast')
#ax.plot(t, Ls/100000, 'black', alpha=1, lw=2, label='latent slow')
#ax.plot(t, I*100000, 'green', alpha=1, lw=2, label='infected')
#ax.plot(t, R*100000, 'red', alpha=1, lw=2, label='recovered')
ax.plot(t[1:], J_diff*100000, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2, label='incidence')
ax.plot(t[1:]+500, J_diffint*100000, 'red', alpha=1, lw=2, label='intervention incidence')
#ax.plot(t, cInc, 'red', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Prevalence')
ax.set_xlabel('Time in years')
ax.set_ylabel('Number')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
legend = ax.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
plt.title("Intervention")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Set [`xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

Comment: @WakemeUpNow Where/how do I set this?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423158/how-do-i-change-the-range-of-the-x-axis-with-datetimes-in-matplotlib)

Comment: None of this is helping. I am trying to set years from 2020 to 2030 in my example.