# Python: 3D plot with Time Index Label

Tags: python, graph, plot, pandas, 3d

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
                        Mid Quote  Volume
2011-01-06 14:25:00     31.035       10
2011-01-06 14:25:01     32.085       42
2011-01-06 14:25:02     32.900       100
```

`df.index`

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-06 14:25:00, ..., 2011-01-06 14:45:00]
Length: 1201, Freq: S, Timezone: None
```

I want to do a 3D plot as follow:

```
td = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
td.scatter(df.index.time, df['Mid Quote'].values, df['Volume'].values)
td.set_xlabel('Time')
td.set_ylabel('Mid Quote')
td.set_zlabel('Volume')
plt.show()
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

I know the issue is with `df.index.time` since if I replace this by `range(0,len(df.Volume))`, I get the plot.

I also tried to replace `df.index.time` with a new variable `time` where

```
time = [y[0].time() for y in df.iterrows()]

>>>time

datetime.time(14, 44, 55), datetime.time(14, 44, 56), datetime.time(14, 44, 57), datetime.time(14, 44, 58), datetime.time(14, 44, 59), datetime.time(14, 45)]...
```

How can I get the time on the x-axis?

Comment: I solved my issue with the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib

Comment: Do you want me to close as duplicate?

Comment: @Veedrac yes if possible. Thank you Veedrac