# Required format for month-day-year plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a .csv file with one column containing the date using backslashes '/' to separate the month, day and year in one column.  The following three columns contain a mean financial value, an upper financial value and a lower financial value.  The data format look like the following example;

```
3/2/14  18338.98    18734.07    17943.88
3/3/14  18280.09    18675.2     17884.99
3/4/14  18220.26    18614.53    17825.98
3/5/14  18160.29    18551.71    17768.87
```

How can I get python to read in the date column and recognize it as a date in the format of month, day, year for eventual plotting with matlibplot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting time in python with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1574088/2823755).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `datetime` module to create a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('3/5/14', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 5, 0, 0)
```

Use the `strftime` method to create labels for the axis `ticks`.

```
>>> dt.strftime('%d%b%Y')
'05Mar2014'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this gets me started!