# Plotting in python over a time period

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a csv file and I want to plot my x,y values over 3 seconds. So when the page loads my graph starts plotting values and in 3 seconds it would've plotted all the values.

Are there any libraries that cater to this functionality?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Matplotlib animation documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). Specifically:

```
matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, **kwargs)
```

You'll have to define the plotting function to be animated