# plotting datetimes after being converted to datetimes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I figured out how to convert my list of datetimes into string using a technique slightly different than what was presented on stackoverflow, but now I would like to plot the array datetimes_final that I appended to when I converted my string to datetimes from the final_times array, but I keep getting the error ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, when my final_times and temp array do have the same number of elements in order to be plotted so I do not understand why I am getting this error, and need help fixing it.  I also posted the error I am getting but I did not post the entire error since it's over 200 lines so I just posted the important part.

```
def values_equal_np_array3(temp, time_created_index, time_modified_index, times_from_text_file):
    if (len(np.unique(temp)) == 1):
        return True
    else:
        #tells user the temps are not equal for a specified interval of time
        print ('False')

        #specifying the beginning to end interval of temperature collection
        final_times = times_from_text_file[time_created_index: time_modified_index]

        #create a new empty list to hold datetimes
        datetimes_final = []

        #iterate over the empyty list
        for element in final_times:
            datetime_conversion = datetime.datetime.strptime(element, "%H:%M")
            datetimes_final.append(datetime_conversion)        


        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature')
        plt.title('Time vs Temperature')        


        #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib

        #I am trying to plot two arrays-one in datetimes and another in ints- using the link above

        final_times = matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetimes_final)
        matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(final_times, temp)


        #the values that appear in the non-uniform temperature array on display as an array        
        return np.unique(temp)

#test case for the values_equal_np_array3 function
#the first 6 times from the times_from_text_file array should be plotted against the temp array 
values_equal_np_array3(np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 0, 5, np.array(['10:15','12:31','12:32','1:33', '12:34', '1:35', '2:36', '2:37', '3:38', '1:39']))


False

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-c16b47f0901d> in <module>()
----> 1 values_equal_np_array3(np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 0, 5,         np.array(['10:15','12:31','12:32','1:33', '12:34', '1:35', '2:36', '2:37', '3:38', '1:39']))

<ipython-input-78-67671c2f9e11> in values_equal_np_array3(temp,     time_created_index, time_modified_index, times_from_text_file)
     23 
     24         final_times = matplotlib.dates.date2num(datetimes_final)
---> 25         matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(final_times, temp)
     26 
     27 

C:\Users\mintw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in     _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    217         y = _check_1d(y)
    218         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 219             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
    220         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    221             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Comment: So do your x and y arrays have the same first dimension?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the 2 arrays are the same size.  One has 6 ints, the other 10 times.

Comment: So that is true which is why time_created_index and my time_modifed_index represents a beginning to end range of times to graph which in this case will be 6 time values against the 6 temp values.  In the function itself, I represent time_created_index and time_modified_index in the line of code final_times = times_from_text_file[time_created_index: time_modified_index] which represents the range I want for final_times on the plot.
 With that said, I do not understand why even though I am plotting the same dimensions, I am getting the error saying that x and y must be the same first dimension?