# Scatter plot from index column against another column of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks as shown

[image: in this image].

The column `localhour` is the index. My question is how can I use plot scatter to scatter the `localhour` column (the index) with `use` column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib