# display last N values in x axis rang as label in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab-figure

In my python script df.Value have set of n values(200). I need last 100 values as my x axis label like last 100-200 index values.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(df['Time'], df['sale'], label='sales')
plt.xlabel('Time ')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.title('sales')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

its show 0-200 value in x axis but i need last N values in x axis label
sample data

### sample data

sales and time

- 1    604.802656  13:00:00
- 2    604.400000  13:01:00
- 3    604.900024  13:02:00
- 4    604.099976  13:03:00
- 5    604.000000  13:04:00
- 6    604.250000  13:05:00
- 7    604.400024  13:06:00
- 8    604.150024  13:07:00
- 9    604.000000  13:08:00

Comment: Can we provide some part of your input data.

Comment: 1      13:01:00
2      13:02:00
3      13:03:00
4      13:04:00
5      13:05:00
6      13:06:00
7      13:07:00
8      13:08:00

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(100),df['Time'].values[100:200])
```

thid will help you to shows 100 x axis label in last 100 values

Answer (score 0):

try this

`plt.xticks(np.arange(100, 200, step=1))`

for your case i.e. Time on x-axis you can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428019/5202279

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have take the axis label as in my data set values

Comment: Can you please given an explanation why this works?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(df['Time'], df['sale'], label='sales')
plt.xlabel('Time ')
plt.xticks(np.arrange(100),df.Time[100:200],rotation=45)
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.title('sales')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

- np.ararange(100) indicate  100 X axis value want to show
- and df.Time[100:200] get the last 100 string value from data set df.Time
- rotate the labe 45 degree

thanks for your support