# Plotting datetimes in matplotlib producing many colors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I new to python, trying to plot datetime data in matlibplot, but getting a strange result - I can only plot points and they are myriad different colors. I am using `plot_date()`.

I tried generating a workable example but the problem wouldn't show up there (see below). So here is a sample of the database that is giving problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get a sense of what the data looks like:
data.head()

out:
                         date     variable      value unit
0  2020-04-17 10:30:02.309433  Temperature  20.799999    C
2  2020-04-17 10:45:12.089008  Temperature  20.799999    C
4  2020-04-17 11:00:07.033692  Temperature  20.799999    C
6  2020-04-17 11:15:04.457991  Temperature  20.799999    C
8  2020-04-17 11:30:04.996910  Temperature  20.799999    C

data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 99 entries, 0 to 196
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   date      99 non-null     object 
 1   variable  99 non-null     object 
 2   value     98 non-null     float64
 3   unit      99 non-null     object 
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 3.9+ KB

#convert date variable to datetime 
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

#plot with plot_date, calling date2num on date variable
plt.plot_date([mdates.date2num(data['date'])], [data['value']])
```

Gives:
[image]

Why am I getting all these colored points? When I build a small data set of three time periods I don't see this behavior. Instead I get three blue points:

```
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['2020-04-17 10:30:02.309433', '2020-04-17 10:30:02.309455', '2020-04-17 10:45:12.089008'], 
    'value': [20.799999, 41.099998, 47.599998]})

#change time variable to datetime object
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

#plot
plt.plot_date(mdates.date2num(df['time']), df['value'])
```

Gives three blue dots as expected:

[image]

Finally, how can I produce a line plot using `plot_date()`. The only way I have seen to do this is using: `datetime.datime.now()` date formats and calling `pyplot.plot()` - see second answer here: [Plotting time in Python with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `plt.plot_date([mdates.date2num(data['date'])], [data['value']])` and `plt.plot_date(mdates.date2num(df['time']), df['value'])` is that you have an extra set of square brackets.

As for the line, add `fmt='-'` option to `plot_date`