# Pandas read CSV datetime column plotting

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I’m using Pandas to import data from a csv. One of the columns is datetime. I'm using...

```
datetime = ['datetime']
df= pd.read_csv(File, parse_dates=datetime)
```

...to import the datetime column as "datetime64[ns]", which according to...

```
df.info()
```

...is in the correct format. However, when i plot against the "datetime" column it looks like this:

[image]

When it should be looking like this (this is how it looks when I'm working directly with the same data directly extracted from SQL).

[image]

I assume the datetime column is still not quite in the correct dtype (even though it states it is datetime64[ns]).

What should i do to ensure that the 1st plot looks like the 2nd?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib

Comment: Can you also mention what have you tried and what exactly does y axis represent?

Comment: Does the data need to first be sorted on the datetime column?