# Using datetime object for a scatter plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

I would like to construct a scatter plot, using date time objects on both axis. Namely, dates (formatted as `%YYYY-MM-DD`) will be placed on one axis, the second axis will display 24 hour scale (i.e. from 0 to 24) and contain timestamps of events (formatted as `%HH:MM` in 24-hour format), such a user logging into the server, that occurred on a given date. There could be several events on a particular date, for example, a user logging 2 or 3 times.

**My questions:** how do I use such `datetime` objects, while creating a plot using `matplotlib`? Do I need to convert them in order to feed into `matplotlib`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, here is a [full demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_demo_rrule.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-date-demo-rrule-py) from the matplotlib docs.

Comment: No, you can use the list of `datetime.datetime`s right away

Comment: My apologies for not being precise. Being a novice, it is difficult to verbalize the "right" question. I am interested in this part: s = np.random.rand(len(dates))  # make up some random y values -- My "y values" are also datetime objects. Can I plot datetime vs datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1574146/12540580 :

> You must first convert your timestamps to Python `datetime` objects (use `datetime.strptime`). Then use `date2num` to convert the dates to matplotlib format.
>
> Plot the dates and values using [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date):
>
> ```py
> dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(list_of_datetimes)
> matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(dates, values)
> ```

Comment: the post that you are referring to is a bit dated. `matplotlib` can handle `datetime`s directly. So there is no need for conversion

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To more precise, can I use datetime objects for both x and y axis? i.e. can I have a list of values which also contains datetime objects?