# Is it possible to plot by date and time on the x axis with mathplotlib instead of defaulting to day?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that's in the format

| date | class |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2019 17:45 | 1 |
| 01/06/2019 20:23 | 2 |
| 03/06/2019 06:56 | 1 |

I'm trying to plot the changes in class against time using the code below

```
plt.plot_date(x, y, linestyle='solid')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
plt.tight_layout()
```

However the result is, well, a mess. There are numerous entries for each day separated by time but the graph is squashing down the x axis to only show the days

[image]

Is it possible to expand it so it uses day and time or even day and time in bins?

Comment: to me, the problem seems to be your range of date/time (2016-05 to 2016-06). if you want to see a certain section of the data in more detail, you'll have to change the xrange

Comment: Does something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574088/15740324) help?