# multiple plots on the same figure, time coordinates, using python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot multiple plots on the same figure using python. The graph should be **linear**, the x coordinates represent the time of the day, and the y coordinates match the values. Each plot matches a different date.

The data is stored inside a dictionary. The keys represent the dates, and the values hold 2 lists: the first matches the x coordinates, and the second matches the y coordinates.
For example:

```
dict_data = {"4 April": [[datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 59), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 1), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 8), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 50)], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 10), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 40), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 8), datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 10)], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}
```

I found apost on stack overflow Plotting time in Python with Matplotlib. It was'nt helpful because the x-axis on the graph they created is in "datetime" type, while I use "datetime.time"datetime". (I don't want the x-axis to show the dates). Also, the graph they created is a scatter plot, while I need it to be linear.

This is what I tried:

```
def multiple_plots(dict_data):
"""
Method to plot multiple times in one figure.
It receives a dictionary with the representation of the data in the csv file.
Every key in the dictionary represent a different date that will have its own plot ont the graph.
"""
for date, coordinates in dict_data.items():
    time_coordinates = coordinates[0]
    # converting the x coordinates in the type datetime.time to int
    x_coordinates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(time_coordinates)
    val_coordinates = coordinates[1]
    plt.plot(list(map(int, x_coordinates)), list(map(int, val_coordinates)), label=date)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: use datetime.datetime, not datetime.time - you can easily remove the dates from the labels with a DateFormatter; some ideas e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574088/10197418).

Comment: @MikaLittor if an answer helped, accept that answer. I don't get how you keep editing your question, expanding it and expect others to answer. Give those who answer their due credit. Upvote and accept the answer that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just work without any fuss:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

dict_data = {"4 April": [[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 59), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 1), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 8), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 50)], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 10), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 8), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 10)], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k in dict_data:
    ax.plot(dict_data[k][0], dict_data[k][1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Obviously that looks a little cramped, but if you use concise converter:

```
plt.rcParams['date.converter'] = 'concise'
```

then you get[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Edit based on edit in question

The code, using `plot_date` and line type `'-'`.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict_data = {"4 April": [[np.datetime64("2022-07-01T22:59:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:01:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:08:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:50:00")], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[np.datetime64("2022-07-01T08:10:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T09:40:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T11:08:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T11:10:00")], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}
# dict_data = {"4 April": [[datetime(2022, 7, 1, 22, 59), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 1), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 8), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 50)], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[datetime(2022, 7, 1, 8, 10), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 9, 40), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 11, 8), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 11, 10)], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}

def multiple_plots(dict_data):
    """
    Method to plot multiple times in one figure.
    It receives a dictionary with the representation of the data in the csv file.
    Every key in the dictionary represent a different date that will have its own plot ont the graph.
    """
    for date, coordinates in dict_data.items():
        time_coordinates = coordinates[0]
        # converting the x coordinates in the type np.datetime64 t2022-07-01To int
        x_coordinates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(time_coordinates)
        val_coordinates = coordinates[1]
        plt.plot_date(list(map(int, x_coordinates)), list(map(int, val_coordinates)), '-', label=date)

    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

multiple_plots(dict_data)
```

Final Output:
[image]

---

---

The `date2num` function requires the year, month and date in addition to time. So, two simple fixes are:

1. Sending in year, month and time

```
dict_data = {"4 April": [[datetime(2022, 7, 1, 22, 59), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 1), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 8), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 23, 50)], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[datetime(2022, 7, 1, 8, 10), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 9, 40), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 11, 8), datetime(2022, 7, 1, 11, 10)], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}
```

2. Sending in `np.datetime64` type

```
dict_data = {"4 April": [[np.datetime64("2022-07-01T22:59:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:01:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:08:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T23:50:00")], [405, 320, 300, 360]], "5 April": [[np.datetime64("2022-07-01T08:10:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T09:40:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T11:08:00"), np.datetime64("2022-07-01T11:10:00")], [120, 20, 10, 0]]}
```

They both work. The final plot is:
[image: Final Output]

Comment: You could take the min and max values, convert to string and add ":" maybe?

Comment: Please check the edit I added to this post.

Comment: Thank you. but still this is not what I meant. I want the x-axis to match the time of the day so I wull able to see that on 10:00 AM the values on April 4th were 200, while on April 5th they were 300.